# Upgrading from .NET 6.0 to .NET 7.0

Tags: upgrade, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

For a current visual studio 2022 solution I am trying to change the target framework from .NET 6.0 to .NET 7.0. I have downloaded the sdk for this and if I go to create a new solution, .NET 7.0 is now an option for the targeted framework. However, for a current solution, the highest I can still go is .NET 6.0

[image]

I've been trying to look online, and changed it visual studio to preview mode but that didn't change anything, what do I need to do in order for .NET 7.0 to be an option here? If I just try change the .csproj file I get the error "*The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0. Either target .NET6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0*". What am I missing here?

Edit:

I have noticed as well that even if I create a new project within the existing solution,.NET 7.0 is an option for the targeted framework, it's just not an option for the existing ones for some reason

Comment: This is a very useful and relevant piece of documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70 Even if not using ASP.NET Core, read it. Do not miss the link to the list of breaking changes at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out what was going on. There is a global.json file which I didn't realise was there. It was set up like so:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.100",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

I just needed to change it to:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.100",
    "rollForward": "latestMinor"
  }
}
```

Doing this solved my problem and I was then able to select .NET 7.0 as the targeted framework

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to update the .csproj file

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I had to change TargetFramework from net6.0 to net7.0